# FLTK 1.3.4 Fl_Native_File_Chooser corrupting return stack on 64-bit Lubuntu

Tags: segmentation-fault, filechooser, fltk

Declaring a local `Fl_Native_File_Chooser` object hammers the return stack upon routine exit.  Have also seen the fail be delayed to the parent routine calling the routine, that is, if `A()` calls method `B()` declares the object, then `B()` can return safely but `A()` dies upon its return.

Applies May '17 with FLTK 1.3.4-1 release Nov 15 2016 on 64-bit Lubuntu using `-std=gnu++11` in compilation.

Fl_Native_File_Chooser appeared to be working last year in 32-bit Lubuntu without the `-std=gnu++11`, or at least it returned without crashing.  However, we did have some mysterious memory corruption, so it's hard to tell.

```
#include <FL/Fl_Native_File_Chooser.H>

void A()
{
    Fl_Native_File_Chooser fnfc;
    printf("A all finished, trying to return.\n");
}

int main( )
{    
    printf("Calling A.\n");
    A();
    printf("A returned.\n");
}
```

gives

```
Calling A.
A all finished, trying to return.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:  Use a global object allocated off the heap, then keep it around:

```
Fl_Native_File_Chooser * p_fnfc = new Fl_Native_File_Chooser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was caused by key portions of Lubuntu updating themselves invisibly behind my back, creating an incompatibility.

The correct answer seems to be rebuild FLTK, even from the same source code as before, and then reinstall it.
This time I did:

```
autoconf
./configure --enable-xft --enable-debug --enable-threads --enable-xdbe --with-abiversion=10304
sudo make
sudo make install
```

and now the test case works.